INVALID_SESSION_ID Session expired or invalid when calling from SSH wall
I recently created a new Salesforce Dev account following the guide here. I need to use the API from behind an SSH wall.  From SSHed system, I was able to authenticate, get the access token and get all the versions. But, when I query the services, I get an error:
curl ${SF_URL}/services/data/v60.0/ -H "Autorization: Bearer $SF_TOKEN"

Error:
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Note from my regular system, I'm able to authenticate and query the API. I followed the guide here to update my settings as follows, but no avail.
Session Settings 
Connected Apps (Salesforce CLI) > OAuth 
